# Error trying to create itunes app store test user; Could not convert Apple ID account to iTunes store account

Tags: objective-c, ios4, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

**What I am trying to do:**
create a test user for testing in app purchase in my app.

**What I am doing:**

1. Logging into itunes connect.
2. Clicking on Manage Users
3. Clicking on Test User
4. Filling out the form.

**What Error I am getting:**
Could not convert Apple ID account to iTunes store account.

Doesnt seem to matter how I fill that form out I keep getting the above error.  What am I doing wrong?

If I then try and resubmit the form again i get:

The email address you entered already belongs to an existing Apple account. Please try again.,

However when I look at my users it tells me I dont have any and when I try and use one I created it doesn't let me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had accepted all agreements, and apparently time heals all wounds because as of 11/19/2011 its back up and working.

Comment: I think you mean "accepted", which has almost the opposite meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today as well. When I went to go create a test user this morning, it would give me the same error. Just a few minutes ago I thought I'd give it another try and when I logged in, I noticed that I needed to accept a new agreement amendment (which I had forgotten to do this morning). After accepting the agreement, I was then able to create a test account without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I switched *Country* to *United States* - and it helped me to fix the issue & to create in-app test user.

Comment: what if we want to create test users for other apple store and not for US ?